# why is my css speech bubble displaced so frequently? How can I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used css3 methods to draw out speechbubble.

Sometimes when i load my website the speechbubble gets displaced.

See http://cl.ly/image/1A0Y3z401D23

**Then I have to press the refresh button a couple of times before it gets rendered the proper way.**

See http://cl.ly/image/3V043M1K1l0n

**NOTE** : there is no successful or failing markup. It's the same markup all the time.

I tested this with chrome and it happens quite frequently. You can view one of the public pages here http://storyzer.com/faq

** **EDIT** **

I am adding this code because of a comment I needed to show some code.

the css code responsible for the drawing of the speech bubble

```
/******** talkbubble_left **************/
.gradient_header_talkbubble {
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f8f8f9 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#f8f8f9)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f8f8f9 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f8f8f9 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f8f8f9 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#f8f8f9 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f8f8f9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.talkbubble_left {
    position: relative;
    background: #white;
    border: 1px solid #DCDDDE;
}
.talkbubble_left:after, .talkbubble_left:before {
    right: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 50%;
}
.talkbubble_left:after {
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid #FBFBFB;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.talkbubble_left:before {
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid #DCDDDE;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    margin-top: -6px;
}

#header .talkbubble{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    height: 47px;   
    width: 889px;
    float: right;   
}
```

How do I prevent this using code? could be javascript or css or html or anything.

Comment: Without seeing the successful and failing mark-up, it is difficult to help. Don't expect people to reverse-engineer your page. Post a code sample in your question.

Comment: I don't want to indiscriminately paste my entire css file and html markup here either.

Let me start by pasting the css code responsible for the drawing of the speechbubble.

And there is no successful and failing markup. Its the same markup that somehow is showing up the 2 different images I pasted here.

I am not entirely sure if that would help.

Comment: Float both elements left and get rid of the excess `position: relative;`

Comment: @twodayslate float which element? and i have already set float: right for the entire bubble itself in another css rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

float `.bot50x50` and `.talkbubble` both left and get rid of all the `position: relative;` styles unless absolutely needed.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: thank you for your advice. I used extra divs plus the css style called table-cell and table-row to help remove the problem that float: right causes.